Unresolved reference: tensorflow
I am working with artificial intelligence models and Flutter, and in this context, I need to use some Kotlin code in my project. However, when I import the TensorFlow packages into the file, I get the error 'Unresolved reference: tensorflow' and cannot use the package.
There is my gradle file:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties")
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionCode")
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = "1"
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionName")
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = "1.0"
}

android {
    namespace = "x.x.xxx"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    dependencies {

        implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.16.1'
        implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:2.16.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tflite-java:16.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tflite-gpu:16.2.0'
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
        implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.4.4'
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress 'tflite'
        noCompress 'lite'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "x.x.xxx"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdk = flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName = flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}


If you need any details to help with the solution, I will show them right away. Thank you in advance for everything.

What is the path of the file in which you are trying to access TensorFlow classes? For completeness, you might include the contents of this file
